# Change Woocommerce In Stock/Out Stock Text

Tags: woocommerce

I have seen examples on here where you add some text to the functions.php. However how would I change it from its current text which is

10 in stock to Only 10 left so that it keeps the quantity. And then when its sold out it says Sold Out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick way to change the "Out of Stock" text to "Sold Out"

```
function so_28107321_availability( $availability, $product ){
    if( $availability['class'] == 'out-of-stock' ){ 
        $availability['availability'] = 'Sold Out';
    } 
    return $availability;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'so_28107321_availability', 10, 2 );
```

The "10 left" will automatically switch to "Only 10 left" if the stock quantity is below the `woocommerce_notify_low_stock_amount` option value. In your WooCommerce settings, you could set this value very high so that it would always say that.

Comment: Thanks for that I will try the code above. How would I change it so that the value is very high, so that it would always say for example

Only (quanity) Left

Comment: It is in your settings. WooCommerce>Settings>Products>Inventory